# epstopdf / ghostscript can't find fonts

Tags: fonts, texlive, linux, ghostscript, epstopdf

I have the following setup

```
$ epstopdf --version
epstopdf ($Id: epstopdf.pl 31784 2013-09-27 22:43:16Z karl $) 2.18

$ gs --version
9.10

$ tex --version
TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2014/dev)

$ uname -a
Linux escritorio-01 3.12.5-302.fc20.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 17 20:42:32 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm tryng to convert some .eps file to .pdf. I'm running the following command

```
$ epstopdf untitled.eps --debug
* kpsewhich command: kpsewhich
* Input filename: untitled.eps
* Output filename: untitled.pdf
* BoundingBox comment: %%BoundingBox:
* Ghostscript command: gs
* Compression: on
* Embedding: on
* Rotation: None
* Resolution: [use gs default]
* Ghostscript pipe: gs -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=untitled.pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dAutoRotatePages=/None - -c quit
* Binary junk at start of file: 0 byte(s)
* Scanning header for BoundingBox
* Old BoundingBox: 81 227 529 564
* New BoundingBox: 0 0 448 337
* Offset: -81 -227
GPL Ghostscript 9.10 (2013-08-30)
Copyright (C) 2013 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/NimbusSanL-Regu.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusSanL-Regu.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/NimbusSanL-Regu.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusSanL-Regu.
Querying operating system for font files...
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/NimbusSanL-Regu.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusSanL-Regu.
Didn't find this font on the system!
Substituting font Courier for NimbusSanL-Regu.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/NimbusMonL-Regu.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusMonL-Regu.
Can't find (or can't open) font file /usr/share/ghostscript/9.10/Resource/Font/NimbusMonL-Regu.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusMonL-Regu.
Didn't find this font on the system!
Unable to substitute for font.
Error: /invalidfont in /findfont
Operand stack:
   120   Helvetica   ISOLatin1Encoding   Helvetica   Helvetica
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   1883   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1867   1   3   %oparray_pop   1755   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   1836   5   5   %oparray_pop
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1174/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:82/200(L)--   --dict:94/160(L)--   --dict:8/85(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Not a directory
GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
epstopdf ($Id: epstopdf.pl 31784 2013-09-27 22:43:16Z karl $) 2.18
!!! Error: Writing to gs failed, error code 1
```

This generate a .pdf file blank.
There seems to be a related discussion [in this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=921706), about some cache that failed to update.
But the technical level of the thread surpass me. I really don't know anything about ghostscript. 
Nevertheless, it looks like the problem it's not so much that ghostscript can't find the Nimbus* fonts, but that it fails to substitute them.
Can anybody help me? Thanks!

EDITED: SOLUTION FOUND.
I added the answer below. Thanks everybody

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you *really* have TeX Live 2014/dev?

Comment: Just a tip: if you have Inkscape you can export using terminal. Type `man inkscape` and see the export options.

Comment: @egreg yeah, I was surprised, because usually Fedora lags in their TexLive distribution by one or even two years. But I installed it from Fedora 20 official repository, so it looks like they really want their _bleeding edge_ badge.

Comment: Where is Fedora getting it from? There is no branch in svn as far as I can see. Usually, TL YYYY is frozen before they start putting together TL YYYY+1. So once the development version of 2013 was available, for example, no further updates were made to 2012. Doesn't mean that's true this year, of course. I'm just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally managed to solve the problem, kind of. This is more a solution than an answer.
Apparently, [there is some kind of conflict](http://www.infinality.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=238) between ghostscript and the [infinality package](http://www.infinality.net/) used for better font rendering in Unix (Fedora's default font render is hideous). So I have to remove infinality :(

```
$ sudo yum remove -y freetype-infinality
```

And that's it, **epstopdf**  worked again. And now I have horrible fonts again!

Maybe someone who understand a little more about fonts, ghostscript and infinality could add to this thread a real answer of what is happening; and not just a simple solution like mine. Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/38226#comment117625 and the linked bug report?

Answer (score 1):

You can always tell Ghostscript specifically where to look for fonts, using the
`-sFONTPATH=...` switch directly on the command line:

```
  gs -sFONTPATH=/usr/share/fonts;/some/other/path [...rest of command...]
```

Alternatively, you can set the `GS_FONTPATH` environment variable.

For multiple font directories, use a semicolon `;` as a separator.